# Is Google Cloud Vision API deprecated?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

While browsing some documentation for Google Cloud Vision, I came across a page describing a deprecation that will happen at the end of this month: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/deprecations.

I am not certain if I am impacted by this. I only use **full_text_annotation** and **text_annotations** from Cloud Vision API for doing OCR, but I'm not sure about their product names and whether this announcement would impact what I'm currently doing...

Can someone confirm whether or not I would be impacted? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vision API is in active development. The most recent model upgrades were December 5, 2023 which became the default models in March 2024. https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes

AutoML Vision is a separate product that was moved to Vertex.

Answer (score 1):

The AutoML Vision API is the one scheduled for depreciation by the end of March 2024, as highlighted in the public document.

> This legacy version of AutoML Vision is [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/deprecations) and will no longer be available on Google Cloud after March 31, 2024. All the functionality of legacy AutoML Vision and new features are available on the Vertex AI platform. See [Migrate to Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/migrating-to-vertex-ai) to learn how to migrate your resources.

You will still be able to continue using the **full_text_annotation** and **text_annotations** services by [migrating to Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/migrating-to-vertex-ai).